# How do you plot $y = 2x \sin x$ at the point $(\pi/2, \pi)$ with showing the tangent line $y = 2x$?

Tags: plotting

How do you plot $y = 2x \sin x$ at the point $(\pi/2,\pi)$ with showing the tangent line $y = 2x$? I can't seem to plot the point with both the sin graph as well as the tangent on the same graph.

Comment: I think your expression is wrong. What do you mean by 2x sin?

Comment: sorry I meant y = 2x sin x

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do it. Maybe this is easier for you to understand:

```
plot1 = Plot[2*x*Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
plot2 = Plot[2 x, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

I suggest you have a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html where you can find Basic Examples to help you get started.

Comment: thank you for the help!

Comment: If you are satisfied, then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f, tangent]
f[x_] := 2 x Sin[x];
tangent[f_, x0_][x_] := ConditionalExpression[f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0), 
   x0 - 1/2 <= x <= x0 + 1/2];

Plot[{f[x],  tangent[f, Pi/2][x]}, {x, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> {{Pi/2}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also calculating the tangent in this example.

```
f = 2 x Sin[x];
x1 = Pi/2;
f1 = f /. x -> x1;
df1 = D[f, x] /. x -> x1;
```

Form the tangent and plot it together with the function.

```
tangent = f1 + df1 (x - x1);
Plot[{f, tangent}, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {{}, Blue},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{x1, f1}]}]
```

[image]